# Mobile, hands free (audio only) ear training

Tags: android, audio, music, educational

I have a commute that lasts 20-60 minutes.  During that commute, I want my Android phone to play [ear training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_training) exercises for me.  Since I will be driving, it is required that I do not need to interact with the phone in any way.  Once started, it should play exercises until stopped.

Ear training consists of short musical sequences which the listener must identify.  For example, the app might play a C followed by a D; the listener should be able to identify this as a major 2nd interval.  This is just one type of ear training exercise; there are many others.

Requirements:

- Must run on Android 5.1.1
- Must be hands free (don't need to tap/swipe the screen)
- Should be eyes free (don't need to look at the screen)

Nice to have:

- Plays exercises until told to stop
- After each interval, rhythm, etc., pauses some time before announcing the correct answer.
- Has interval recognition exercises.

Things I don't care about:

- I don't mind paying money for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have developed an app that does just what you describe.

Currently it features intervals, chords, scales, and perfect pitch training. There is also a random mode where you can shuffle all the above.
I intend to add more functionality soon.

If you want to give it a try, here it is:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.harelf.hands_free_ear_trainer

It is not currently free, but the price is very modest ($0.99USD).

Hope you like it!

Comment: Shalom Avocado!  Thank you for posting about your new app. I look forward to trying it soon!

Comment: I installed this and it looks like exactly what I had in mind when I asked my question.  The UI is simple and clean, making it easy to set up an exercise at a stoplight without taking a lot of time or diverting my attention from the traffic signals.

Answer (score 1):

[Functional Ear Trainer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaizen9.fet.android) by Kaizen9 Apps has a "Listener" mode that plays exercises continuously, without interaction, until told to stop.

The exercises in Functional Ear Trainer are not based on intervals, but on tonal centers.  With traditional interval training, you might be presented with a G followed by a B and are expected to recognize that as an ascending major 3rd.  With tonal center training, you might be presented with GMaj/CMaj/DMaj/GMaj (I/IV/V/I) chords to set the tonal center (G Major), and then you are played the note B and expected to recognize that as the 3rd degree of the scale.

The basic app is free, but Listener Mode is an in-app purchase.  I don't remember how much Listener Mode costs by itself; $15.99 gets you every add-on the app has.